# Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm using a very good desktop machine with very good configuration 8 GB ram and a lot of free space too.

while running the app in my device android studio is giving me this error all the time,

```
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

**my studio64.exe.vmoptions file**

```
-Xms256m

-Xmx1024m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50

-da

-Djna.nosys=true

-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true

-Djna.debug_load.jna=true

-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.2

-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio

-Didea.jre.check=true
```

please let me know .. I have disabled instant run feature too.

Comment: change your -Xmx setting from -Xmx1024m to a higher value (e.g. -Xmx2048m). -Xmx specifies the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below lines to your build.gradle file.

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
 }
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting **CMS garbage collection has a bad effect on JVM's dimensioning of the JVM "New Space"**. If that space is too small, then you'll constantly see (young generation) GC, which may lead to your problem.

E.g.,

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -version
```

reports just 160 MB of "New space", despite of a total 4 GB heap size. This was on a 2 core system (the number increases with the number of cores), using JVM 1.7.0_75.

You should **check what's your result using a similar command** -- look for the line `par new generation   total ...K`. If the number appears very low, then this is the root cause of your problem.

**You can then solve this by adding the options `-XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:NewSize=512m`**, which will explicitly...

- apply the standard dimensionsing rule for the *upper limit* on "New space" to one third of the available heap space
- set the *minimum* "New space" size to 512m

In general, you should be very careful with tuning the GC settings, like, adding `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` -- without that option, the bad dimensioning wouldn't appear in the first place.